# Passing arguments to g++

Tags: bash, find, g++

I want to create a bash command for recursively finding all c++ files then  returning last changed file (single file) and compile it, so far I wrote this `find . -name '*.cpp' -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' {} + | sort -nr | head -n 1` it gives me last changed file but when to my command `| g++` I get error `no input files`. How I can provide my file to `g++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ doesn't take filename input as a stream

```
g++ "$(find . -name '*.cpp' -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' {} + | sort -nr | head -n 1)"
```

Comment: it works, but by the way, why you used double quotes `g++ "..."`, it works without them too?

Comment: Quotes are for if you have spaces in the filename or path result.  You have to do "/path/to/my file."  If you guarantee there will be no spaces in the path, then it will work without quotes.